# Any UML-like modeling tool for QT signals and slots?

Tags: qt, uml

Is it any uml-like modeling tool available that can design (draw) classes and can visually represent QT signals and slots, they connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) as it supports UML 2.1 and allow to create user defined diagrams.

Comment: Thanks, i will check it. Does desktop edittion (130$) support user defined diagrams? And, maybe you know some tutorial / guide on how to design custom diagram in Architect that closely represents signal-slot relations of runtime objects?

Comment: I've used this tool for several years it allows you to define stereotypes for anything (including methods and fields) you can create one called a "signal" or "slot" and you'll see it in the generated documentation.... Now it's not QT specific, but signals and slots are conceptually similar to events and event handlers in .Net and EA handles those just fine. (It creates a stereotype of event for events that are raised... it doesn't automatically diagram the event handlers, however...)

Answer (score 4):

The signal/slog mechanism is essentially a mechanism for registering callbacks. So your question could be paraphrased as: "How do I model callbacks in UML". I'm not sure if there is a good answer since callbacks are not really an object oriented construction. Conceptually the observer pattern would be closest.

Answer (score 1):

These connections are dynamic, so I'm not sure it's even possible to represent them in a static way (as in a diagram).

Also, most often, they are tightly bound in time and code (i.e. you create two objects and then connect them). From the code, it should be pretty obvious what happens and why, making any extra documentation dangerous (since the best it could do was to document the current state and it would always be in danger to be out of date unless it was generated from the source, or rather from data gathered during the runtime of the application).